# Codeigniter site halting from time to time

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I am developing a site at localhost in CI.

Sometimes (very often) when I refresh the page, it's just loading, loading and nothing happens.

I am using:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

PHP 7.1.32-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (FPM)

ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

I've checked the php slow log and when restart the server, I've got this:

```
[16-Sep-2019 11:04:31]  [pool www] pid 21699
script_filename = /var/www/example.lh/index.php
[0x00007fd8dac177c0] flock() /var/www/example.lh/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php:180
[0x00007fd8dac17370] read() /var/www/example.lh/system/libraries/Session/Session.php:143
[0x00007fd8dac17320] session_start() /var/www/example.lh/system/libraries/Session/Session.php:143
[0x00007fd8dac16b10] __construct() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:1285
[0x00007fd8dac16340] _ci_init_library() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:1178
[0x00007fd8dac15e00] _ci_load_stock_library() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:1043
[0x00007fd8dac15980] _ci_load_library() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:1089
[0x00007fd8dac15500] _ci_load_library() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:218
[0x00007fd8dac15360] library() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:202
[0x00007fd8dac151c0] library() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:1359
[0x00007fd8dac14dc0] _ci_autoloader() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Loader.php:157
[0x00007fd8dac14d60] initialize() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/Controller.php:79
[0x00007fd8dac14ad0] __construct() /var/www/example.lh/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:518
```

What can cause this halting? It's happens only on my localhost.

Comment: Is it `session_write_close()` issue in the codeigniter ?

Comment: I am using CI 3.1.9. Is it a known bug? What can I do with this?

Comment: Yes it is i have read this from here a long time ago. [Link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#a-note-about-concurrency)

Comment: Thank you, I will read it through.